# Heroku config vars not available on process.env

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm using Heroku and Node, but my config vars are returning as *undefined*

When I issue the command

```
heroku config
```

I see all my config vars, but when I ssh into the server and run

```
node > process.env
```

I don't see the config vars in there.
Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Did you use [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) in your app?

Comment: It's only enabled when NODE_ENV=development, so not on the server, thanks for your reply.

Comment: No problem. Did you try loading your environment variable with process.env.FOO_VARIABLE?

Comment: Yes, I tried in the console. Going into node console modus, and typing process.env, I only saw some default heroku variables set, while I have 6 config vars.

Comment: I see. Can you try this from the **app** itself? You Heroku deployment probably has an entrypoint, for the Node app. I'm thinking maybe Heroku passes the environment variables only to that process

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having same problem.

Comment: @Christy I don't recall! I'm sorry.

Comment: @Notflip no problem, I figured out I needed `webpack.EnvironmentPlugin()` to access client side environmental variables on Heroku : )

Comment: Aah good to know!

Comment: @Notflip can you post an actual answer with some more info?  Thx

Comment: It's been over a year so I don't remember, but I think you just need to enable the webpack.EnvironmentPlugin() in your webpack config file, feel free to answer once you got it working!